# For $p>0$, does $\int_1^\infty x^{-p/x}$ diverge?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

For $p>0$, does $\int_1^\infty x^{-p/x}$ diverge?
I've tried the root test, the comparison test, and the limit comparison test without success. 
Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $x=e^{\ln x}$, we are integrating $\exp(-(p\ln x)/x)$. Since $\frac{\ln x}{x}\to 0$ as $x\to\infty$, the integrand has limit $1$, and therefore in particular is after a while greater than $\frac{1}{2}$.

It follows that the improper integral diverges to $\infty$.

Comment: can you pls explain me how it diverges. I understood that $x^{\frac {-p}{x}} \to 1 $ as $x \to \infty$ It makes given function well-defined and continuous in given interval $[1, \infty)$. So it should be convergent right? but it is divergent. Kindly clarify. I am novice in real analysis and started learning recently.

Answer (score 1):

Hint1: Taylor series expansion.
Hint2: Treat as complex function (asymptotic stability).

:)